# Checkboxes not rendering

Tags: 7

All the other form elements render properly. Radios and Checkboxes do not. The title and descriptions show up, but not the boxes or radios.

```
$options7 = array();
foreach ($resqry1 as $option)
{
  $options7[$option->id] = $option->id;
}

$form = array();
$form['lis'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $options7,
);


return $form;
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked whats in the options array, no zero keys?

Comment: options array have the values of the employee name

Comment: double check "$option" is an array or object. If it is array try $option['id']

Comment: can you please try with static values like `'#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('SAT'), t('ACT'))),` ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation while trying to inject checkboxes to user_register_form. I think checkboxes type is not valid type for typical rendering. Form elements of type checkboxes get totally reformatted within form_builder after form_alter hooks have executed. Make sure that form builder runs after you place your field.